# Optional virtual environment creation error

Tags: python, django

```
"virtualenv" is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

-is the error message that displayed after typing `"mkvirtualenv <name>"`

I am trying to create another virtual environment for a django project

Comment: show the stackerror here

Comment: I guess if you are in virtualenv, you again need to install virtualenv module. But virtualenv within virtualenv, I never did that :/ Is it good practice **Confused**

Comment: Try this command: python -m venv myenv, it should create a virtual environment in your current directory called myenv
https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments

Comment: bdw you are typing ``mkvirtualenv <name>`` and getting error for ``"virtualenv" is not recognized as`` It should be ``mkvirtual is not recognised as..``

Comment: abhikumar22 what is a stackerror?

Comment: Sally Zeitler I have tried the command and did not get any fedback

Comment: PySaad yup and how can i get to the actual fault causing this situation